# Msbuild Autoincrement Version

Tags: c#, cmd, msbuild

```
    <VersionPrefix>0.0.1</VersionPrefix>
```

how to automatically increment the last build digit in a project on every build?

let's say I use the  command:

> msbuild pack

the output is a file called:

```
PackageName_0.0.1.nupkg
```

but how to make it increase every time after every build?

```
msbuild pack -> output file: PackageName_0.0.1.nupkg 

msbuild pack -> output file: PackageName_0.0.2.nupkg 

... 

msbuild pack -> output file: PackageName_0.0.n.nupkg
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'auto increment per build' feature in MSBuild and there really can't be. But you can build your own mechanism or use a tool.

To increment from the last build, you need to know the 'last' build. For your situation, I don't know how 'last build' may be defined. If you have version control and a tool for CI builds, you probably only want to use the CI builds as the 'last build' and not local builds by individual developers.

Azure DevOps Pipelines has variables that can be defined as auto-incrementing and that can be passed to your build as an MSBuild property. Other CI tools will have something similar.

If you need to build your own mechanism you will need to make choices about how and where to store the build version that will be incremented. If builds are distributable across machines, then that stored build version needs to be accessible to the distributed builds.

As a matter of good practice, a build should not make source code changes that must be captured in version control. Builds can't be repeatable if the build itself is changing the source. The build version could be stored in a data store outside of version control but that adds a dependency to the build process.